# Open 'Choose file' window onclick on anchor link (Skip the click on 'Choose file' button)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an anchor `a.add_input` link which is responsable of adding (via jQuery) a `file` input field to the current document. The input is appended to a list of other file input fields (Multiple file uploads in the context of a OneToMany relationship).

The final result looks like this:

```
<input type="file" id="1" name="...">
<input type="file" id="2" name="...">
<input type="file" id="3" name="...">
<input type="file" id="4" name="...">
<a href="#" class="add_input">Add an input</a>
```

As you know, the file input field is rendered with a button that pops up a window. The window allows user to choose  a file. I want to hide that button to end user and allow him to see the window directly after click on anchor. But I additionnally need that the file is linked to its specific input file(a server side code requires it).

I know that maybe I have two issues within this post, but I see them as one issue.

Can someone please correct me or give insights on how to do it? your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps you could have javascript trigger a `click` event on the file input you just dynamically added?

Comment: Not too difficult to do what you want, but from my experience it's never going to work in IE.  Maybe IE11, not sure...  clicking anywhere but on the type=file (and redirecting the click event via javascript) results in an "untrusted" click, and the files will not submit in IE.

Comment: @mituw16 and wwwmary, yes this is the idea behind it, but as a newbie in client-side dev, I prefer ask experienced people to have an optimal solution (esp optimum cross browser)

Comment: I'd suggest using one of the many JQuery plugins that handle multiple file uploads.  They probably won't do exactly this, but you will probably end up with something even better.  If you have to support IE, you're going to hate trying to do this yourself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @phts said, in IE the user has to interact directly with the element (you cannot trigger it programmatically). **However**, you can make the element invisible (via setting it's opacity to 0) and positioning it on top of an anchor tag (or anything) so it appears the user is clicking on a link, when in actual fact they are clicking on a file input (and thus the native file chooser dialog will be shown).

This is the common method to work around the problem you described. Below is an example (in the second div, I left the opacity of the input as 1 so you can see what's happening):

```css
.container { position: relative; margin: 0 0 40px;}
.chooser { position: absolute; z-index: 1; opacity: 0; cursor: pointer;}
.chooser-2 { opacity:1;}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <input type="file" class="chooser">
  <a href="#">Click me to choose a file</a>
  </div>

<div class="container">
  <input type="file" class="chooser chooser-2">
  <a href="#">Click me to choose a file</a>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't need to go all fancy, you can simply use a `<label>`!

```html
<div>
    <label for="file">Click me</label>
    <input type="file" id="file" style="display: none" />
</div>

<div>
    or
    <label>Click me 2
        <input type="file" id="file2" style="display: none" />
    </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Firefox, Chrome allow triggering `click` event on `input file` elements. In this case a native filechooser dialog will be shown.

IE (any versions) doesn't allow such behavior. IE allows choosing file only by user click on Browse button. So it is impossible to open a filechooser dialog on a separate anchor click directly.

Comment: Technically, IE doesn't require a click on the button, but on either the button or the text input that shows the filename.  So you could hide the button, but you still can't click anywhere but on the remaining visible parts of the type=file.

Comment: Agree. I ment that *only user* may interact with a file input directly in IE, not JS